# I am Using LazyHGrid / LazyHStack inside Custom ScrollView(UIScrollView), but lazy nature is not working

Tags: swiftui, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uiviewrepresentable, swiftui-scrollview

Can anybody tell me how can i set offset in a ScrollView?I have checked ScrollTo(), which scroll to index wise. But I want to move scrollview with offset. I have also checked Custom ScrollView( from UIScrollView) which can be used to set and get offset, but LazyHStack/LazyHGrid inside the custom Scrollview causes problem as their lazy nature doesn't work. Can anybody help me with this issue? Custom ScrollView Code Link : https://gist.github.com/jfuellert/67e91df63394d7c9b713419ed8e2beb7

I have tried to update the content size inside of CustomScrollView, it didn't work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/74194806/5133585